# QDockWidget::title (Need to change the font & size)

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have following style sheet set for QDockWidgets in my QT app. All the things mentioned in the style are working except for the font. Why is "font" is not detected & how could I change the font & size of QDockWidget title ?

```
QDockWidget::title
{
    font: 18pt "Roboto Lt";
    background: lightgray;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if the dock is floating or docked?

Comment: When floating title changes to default Windows look & feel. But that is OK, I just want to customize the way it looks, when it is docked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font should be applied to the QDockWidget itself, not to the sub-control ::title

```
QDockWidget { font-family: "Roboto Lt"; font-size: 18pt; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch the font part in the Qt Reference:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-reference.html

Maybe you should try:

```
QDockWidget::title
{
   font-family: "Roboto Lt";
   font-size: 18pt;
   background: lightgray;
   padding-left: 10px; 
   padding-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but to no avail :(

Comment: OK I got what I wanted by changing the font of the QDockWidget


    QDockWidget
    {
       font-family: "Roboto Lt";
       font-size: 18pt;
    }